# dotnet 5.0 Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App on ubuntu

Tags: 20.04, dotnet, crossover

Am running Ubuntu Budgie 20.04 and regularly run .Net apps (that I built) through CrossOver (20.0.4) / Wine. I just built a small WinForms utility in .Net 5.0 and tried to run it in CrossOver. A message box displayed with no text. I figured, OK, .Net 5.0 has not been installed in the bottle. However, it seems .Net 5.0 is not on the list of things to install.

Then I read that .Net 5.0 is designed to work everywhere (like .Net Core). So, I followed [these instructions](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/install/linux-ubuntu) and installed dotnet on my Ubuntu.

When I type

```
dotnet --list-runtimes
```

I get

```
Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 5.0.3 [/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
Microsoft.NETCore.App 5.0.3 [/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]
```

Then I try to run the app and I get

```
It was not possible to find any compatible framework version
The framework 'Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App', version '5.0.0' was not found.
  - No frameworks were found.

You can resolve the problem by installing the specified framework and/or SDK.

The specified framework can be found at:
  - https://aka.ms/dotnet-core-applaunch?framework=Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App&framework_version=5.0.0&arch=x64&rid=ubuntu.20.04-x64
```

When I browse to that link, it redirects here: https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet/5.0/runtime/?utm_source=getdotnetcore&utm_medium=referral and I see download .net for Windows or Linux. However, for Windows I can download for Desktop apps and for Linux only server apps.

When I look here: https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet/6.0 it shows that the desktop framework is only available for Windows

I'm confused because the message dotnet is giving me implies the desktop framework is available for Ubuntu. However, the website makes it look like that is untrue.

Is there a way to install the desktop framework on Ubuntu or should I redo the utility in .Net 4.8 and run it through CrossOver?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot run WPF and WinForms in linux
https://github.com/dotnet/core/issues/4743